# Is 这部电影非常精彩，我很推荐 grammatical, despite the verb 推荐 lacking an object?

Tags: grammar, verbs

> [image: image of study notes]
>
> 这部电影非常精彩，我很推荐。
> This movie is brilliant and I highly recommend it.

At the Glen Waverley library (Melbourne), they have some Chinese study classes, and the above is from their notes.  I was surprised by 我很推荐 not being followed by an object, such as 我很推荐它.

**Question**: Is 这部电影非常精彩，我很推荐 grammatical, despite the verb 推荐 lacking an object?

I asked [Assistant](https://poe.com/s/hurvHY9GQnT8TW0sWSYH) and it said:

> ...the verb "推荐" (tuījiàn) is used without an explicit object.

Maybe this is permissible, but still, the sentence feels like a 语病 to me.

Comment: You are right!  Especially if it is used in Hongkong, (a 语病 to me).

Comment: Would you consider this sentence 这道烤鸡很好吃，我很喜欢 as a 语病?

Answer (score 3):

这部电影非常精彩，我很推荐 is totally fine. Think of [topic +comment] structure

Topic: [这部电影]

comment 1 [非常精彩]

comment 2 [我很推荐]

you can add as many comments as you want and all the comments describe one topic: [这部电影]

Example:

> 这部电影非常精彩，我很推荐，但剧情有点复杂，要用心去看

- 这部电影非常精彩
- 我很推荐(这部电影)
- 但(这部电影)剧情有点复杂
- (这部电影)要用心去看

Basically, all the comments are dependent clause

Comment: 我很推荐这部电影, (因為)"它"非常精彩. "它" describes "这部电影". The reverse shall follow the same pattern, "这部电影非常精彩, 我很推荐"它"."

Answer (score 1):

You can consider 推荐 as an intransitive verb.

Comment: If it is true "这部电影非常精彩, 我很推荐这部电影" would be wrong, but it isn't

Comment: In English, many verbs can both be intransitive and transitive. I was just saying 推荐 maybe used as an intransitive verb. However, it's best not to pigeon hole Chinese with English grammar.

Answer (score 0):

The object to 推荐 is omitted,as the actual object this movie has appeared before.